# Covariance calculation with CUDA

Tags: cuda, covariance, pca

I am implementing Principal Component Analysis (PCA) based face recognition using CUDA. I used orl face database and calculated the mean image and normalized images. **I'm facing a problem in calculating the covariance matrix**.

```
__global__ void mean(int* i_data, int num, int size, int* o_data, int WIDTH, int HEIGHT, int* normalized)
{
  int x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
  int y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
  int idx = x + y * WIDTH;
  int r = 0;
  int idx_z=0;
  for (int z = 0; z < num; ++z)
  {
   idx_z = z * WIDTH*HEIGHT + idx;
   r += i_data[ idx_z ];
  }
   o_data[ idx ] = int(r/num);
   for (int z = 0; z < num; ++z)
  {
   idx_z = z * WIDTH*HEIGHT + idx;
   normalized[idx_z]  = abs(i_data[idx_z] - o_data[idx]); 
  }
}

dim3 dimBlock = dim3(8,4,1);
dim3 dimGrid = dim3(ceil(rows/dimBlock.x) , ceil(cols/dimBlock.y));

mean<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(dev_images, IMAGE_NUM,size,dev_output,rows,cols,dev_normalized);
```

The database images are of size `(92,112)`.

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not make any sense to me.

Covariance calculation in CUDA can be easily performed by using cuBLAS in conjunction with Thrust. Considering `N` realizations of `K` random variables, the covariance estimation formula is the following

[image]

where `qjk`, `j,k=1,...,K` are the covariance estimate values, `Xj` and `Xk` with the `overbars` are the random variable means as estimated from the available realizations.

Below, I'm reporting a fully worked example:

```
#include <cublas_v2.h>

#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/generate.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <thrust/random.h>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "Utilities.cuh"
#include "TimingGPU.cuh"

/*************************************/
/* CONVERT LINEAR INDEX TO ROW INDEX */
/*************************************/
template <typename T>
struct linear_index_to_row_index : public thrust::unary_function<T,T> {

    T Ncols; // --- Number of columns

    __host__ __device__ linear_index_to_row_index(T Ncols) : Ncols(Ncols) {}

    __host__ __device__ T operator()(T i) { return i / Ncols; }
};

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main()
{
    const int Nsamples = 3;     // --- Number of realizations for each random variable (number of rows of the X matrix)
    const int NX    = 4;        // --- Number of random variables (number of columns of the X matrix)

    // --- Random uniform integer distribution between 10 and 99
    thrust::default_random_engine rng;
    thrust::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(10, 99);

    // --- Matrix allocation and initialization
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_X(Nsamples * NX);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < d_X.size(); i++) d_X[i] = (float)dist(rng);

    // --- cuBLAS handle creation
    cublasHandle_t handle;
    cublasSafeCall(cublasCreate(&handle));

    /*************************************************/
    /* CALCULATING THE MEANS OF THE RANDOM VARIABLES */
    /*************************************************/
    // --- Array containing the means multiplied by Nsamples
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_means(NX);

    thrust::device_vector<float> d_ones(Nsamples, 1.f);

    float alpha = 1.f / (float)Nsamples;
    float beta  = 0.f;
    cublasSafeCall(cublasSgemv(handle, CUBLAS_OP_T, Nsamples, NX, &alpha, thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_X.data()), Nsamples, 
                               thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_ones.data()), 1, &beta, thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_means.data()), 1));

    /**********************************************/
    /* SUBTRACTING THE MEANS FROM THE MATRIX ROWS */
    /**********************************************/
    thrust::transform(
                d_X.begin(), d_X.end(),
                thrust::make_permutation_iterator(
                        d_means.begin(),
                        thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0), linear_index_to_row_index<int>(Nsamples))),
                d_X.begin(),
                thrust::minus<float>());    

    /*************************************/
    /* CALCULATING THE COVARIANCE MATRIX */
    /*************************************/
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_cov(NX * NX);

    alpha = 1.f;
    cublasSafeCall(cublasSgemm(handle, CUBLAS_OP_T, CUBLAS_OP_N, NX, NX, Nsamples, &alpha,
                               thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_X.data()), Nsamples, thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_X.data()), Nsamples, &beta,
                               thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_cov.data()), NX));

    // --- Final normalization by Nsamples - 1
    thrust::transform(
                d_cov.begin(), d_cov.end(),
                thrust::make_constant_iterator((float)(Nsamples-1)),
                d_cov.begin(),
                thrust::divides<float>());  

    for(int i = 0; i < NX * NX; i++) std::cout << d_cov[i] << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `linear_index_to_row_index<int>(Nsamples)` you  seem like you wanted to pass number of columns but you pass number of rows instead. Am I right? Also isn't it bad for perf to copy values to device vector one by one like : `for (size_t i = 0; i < d_X.size(); i++) d_X[i] = (float)dist(rng);`?

Comment: @KadirErdemDemir Thank you for pointing out the first issue. Most likely you are right, but I have no time to check it now and I will let you know shortly. Concerning the second issue, it is irrelevant, since efficiently filling the data matrix is not the primary focus of the post, the main interest being the covariance calculation.

Answer (score 2):

I implemented covariance calculator with CUBlas and Cuda Thrust and compared with online co variance calculation tools. It seems mine producing good results. The code below planned to QDA Bayes. So matrix given may contain more than one class. So multiple co variance matrices is calculated. I hope it will be useful for someone.

```
//! Calculates one or more than one coVarianceMatrix given data.
//  There can be many classes since many covariance matrixes.
/*!
    \param inMatrix This vector contains matrix data in major storage. 
    Forexample if inMatrix=[1 2 3 4 5 6] and trialSizes=[2] this means matrix we will work on a matrix like :
        |1 4 |
        |2 5 |
        |3 6 | -> 2 Trials, 3 Features. Columns contains feature rows contains trials (samples)
    \param trialSizes There can be many classes since many covariance matrixes. Samples from all classes will be given with inMatrix.
    But we need to know how many trials(samples) we have for each class. 
    For example if inMatrix=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12] and trialSizes=[2,2] 
    this means matrix we will work on a matrix like :
        |1 4 |  |7 10 |
        |2 5 |  |8 11 |
        |3 6 |  |9 12 |  --> Total number of trials(samples which is total rowCount) 2 + 2 = 4 , 
                             So colSize = inMatrix.size()/4 = 3(feature vector size)
                         --> There is two element in trialSize vec so each vector has to samples
*/
void multiQDACovianceCalculator(std::vector<float>& inMatrix, std::vector<int>& trialSizes)
{
    cublasHandle_t handle; // CUBLAS context
    int classCount = trialSizes.size();
    int rowSize = std::accumulate(trialSizes.begin(), trialSizes.end(), 0);
    int dimensionSize = inMatrix.size() / rowSize;
    float alpha = 1.0f;
    float beta = 0.0f; // bet =1

    thrust::device_vector<float> d_cov1(dimensionSize * dimensionSize);
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_cov2(dimensionSize * dimensionSize);
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_covResult(dimensionSize * dimensionSize);

    thrust::device_vector<float> d_wholeMatrix(inMatrix);
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_meansVec(dimensionSize); // rowVec of means of trials
    float *meanVecPtr = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_meansVec.data());
    float *device2DMatrixPtr = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_wholeMatrix.data());
    auto maxTrialNumber = *std::max_element(trialSizes.begin(), trialSizes.end());
    thrust::device_vector<float> deviceVector(maxTrialNumber, 1.0f);

    cublasCreate(&handle);
    // Inside of for loop  one covariance matrix calculated each time
    for (int i = 0; i < trialSizes.size(); i++)
    {
        // X*transpose(X) / N
        alpha = 1.0f / trialSizes[i];
        cublasSgemm(handle, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_T, dimensionSize, dimensionSize, trialSizes[i], &alpha,
            device2DMatrixPtr, dimensionSize, device2DMatrixPtr, dimensionSize, &beta,
            thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_cov1.data()), dimensionSize);

        // Mean vector of each column
        alpha = 1.0f;
        cublasSgemv(handle, CUBLAS_OP_N, dimensionSize, trialSizes[i], &alpha, device2DMatrixPtr,
            dimensionSize, thrust::raw_pointer_cast(deviceVector.data()), 1, &beta, meanVecPtr, 1);

        // MeanVec * transpose(MeanVec) / N*N
        alpha = 1.0f / (trialSizes[i] * trialSizes[i]);
        cublasSgemm(handle, CUBLAS_OP_T, CUBLAS_OP_N, dimensionSize, dimensionSize, 1, &alpha,
            meanVecPtr, 1, meanVecPtr, 1, &beta,
            thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_cov2.data()), dimensionSize);

        alpha = 1.0f;
        beta = -1.0f;
        //  (X*transpose(X) / N) -  (MeanVec * transpose(MeanVec) / N*N)
        cublasSgeam(handle, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N, dimensionSize, dimensionSize, &alpha,
            thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_cov1.data()), dimensionSize, &beta, thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_cov2.data()), 
            dimensionSize, thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_covResult.data()), dimensionSize);

        // Go to other class and calculate its covarianceMatrix
        device2DMatrixPtr += trialSizes[i] * dimensionSize;
    }
    printVector(d_covResult);
    cublasDestroy(handle);
}
```